# Script to run for all Table Row IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML table with a date input field which currently runs an AJAX script when the date is modified. This is working well, but I now need another version of the script that acts on all table rows on the page to save the user from having to enter the date for each table row (there could be 20 on the page).

I've created another input for marking all the rows but stumped as to how to implement this. Ideally I'd like to pass an array of the table row IDs (e.g. `id="61851"`) to a new script which calls a PHP script that handles the backend updating.

Here's my table:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.uk.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <h1>Items List</h1>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <td>Flag All Received:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="dateReceivedAll" id="dateReceivedAll" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" placeholder="Date Received"></td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Date Received All</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
  <!-- /.col-md-6-->

  <div class="col-md-6">
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-md-6-->



</div>
<!-- /.col-md-8-->


<div class="col-md-4">



</div>
<!-- /.col-md-4-->

</div>
<!-- /.row-->


<div>

  <br />
  <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <th class="text-center" scope="col">Item Tag</th>
      <th class="text-center" scope="col">Serial Number</th>
      <th class="text-center" scope="col">Received Date</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr id="61851">
        <td>61851</td>
        <td>DTZ452432DDF</td>
        <td id="61851"><input type="text" id="61851" class="form-control datepicker" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Date Rec'd" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dateReceived" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="61852">
        <td>61852</td>
        <td>GZF2452542DA</td>
        <td id="61852"><input type="text" id="61852" class="form-control datepicker" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Date Rec'd" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dateReceived" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="61853">
        <td>61853</td>
        <td>TRA3241234ZZ</td>
        <td id="61853"><input type="text" id="61853" class="form-control datepicker" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Date Rec'd" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dateReceived" value=""></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

and here's the current script that runs when you modify an individual date in the last column:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-control.datepicker").change(function() {
    var recid = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
    var dateReceived = $(this).val();
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('updateItem.php', {
      recid: recid,
      dateReceived: dateReceived
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        var ajaxError = (data.text);
        var errorAlert = 'There was an error updating the Date Received - ' + ajaxError + '. Please contact the Help Desk';
        $this.closest('td').addClass("has-error");
        $("#dateReceivedErrorMessage").html(errorAlert);
        $("#dateReceivedError").show();
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        $this.closest('td').addClass("has-success")
        $this.closest('td').removeClass("has-error");
      }

    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an error updating the Date Received - AJAX request error. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus + '. Please contact the Help Desk';
      $this.closest('td').addClass("has-error");
      $("#dateReceivedErrorMessage").html(ajaxError);
      $("#dateReceivedError").show();
    });
  });
});
```

I've added the Date Received All button and separate input field to capture the date all items were received, just not sure how to have that button trigger a similar version of the current JS but this time pass an array of all the id's?

Answer (score 0):

change your `change event` , initialize event as per below method.

```js
 
  $(document).on("change",".form-control.datepicker",function(){
    var recid = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
    var dateReceived = $(this).val();
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('updateItem.php', {
      recid: recid,
      dateReceived: dateReceived
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.error) {
        var ajaxError = (data.text);
        var errorAlert = 'There was an error updating the Date Received - ' + ajaxError + '. Please contact the Help Desk';
        $this.closest('td').addClass("has-error");
        $("#dateReceivedErrorMessage").html(errorAlert);
        $("#dateReceivedError").show();
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        $this.closest('td').addClass("has-success")
        $this.closest('td').removeClass("has-error");
      }

    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an error updating the Date Received - AJAX request error. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus + '. Please contact the Help Desk';
      $this.closest('td').addClass("has-error");
      $("#dateReceivedErrorMessage").html(ajaxError);
      $("#dateReceivedError").show();
    });
  });
```

Comment: I need to pass all table row IDs - in the above example this would be 61851, 61852 and 61853. Not sure how your example solves this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sucess-btn').click(function(){
    var ans = $('.table-condensed>tbody>tr').map(function(c,i,a){
        return $(i).attr('id');
  });
  //ans is an array with numbers
});
```

Add this to your click event and `ans` array will have the IDs of the rows of the table. Add IDs to both table and the button and it will be easier to select the elements from the DOM.